# How do you manage SSL with nginx and docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, https, docker-compose

I'm a bit overwhelmed by the myriad of tutorials and configurations of nginx that don't necessarily fit my usecase, So I'm still confused. I don't necessarily need an answer, but a point to the right direction of how to set up SSL with my set up.

I have 4 services in my docker-compose, frontend(react), api (python/flask), postgres, and nginx.

here is my nginx config

```
upstream frontend {
  server frontend:3333;
}

upstream api {
  server api:8000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend;
  }
  
  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

my nginx service in docker-compose

```
nginx:
        depends_on:
          - api
          - frontend
        restart: unless-stopped
        build: ./nginx
        volumes:
         - ./
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
```

and a Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I just need a point in the right direction of the steps needed to take to get SSL up and running with this configuration

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Certbot` to create (and renew) a free SSL certificate, updating your `docker-compose` accordingly

```
nginx:
 image: nginx:latest
 container_name: nginx
 restart: always
 volumes:
   - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
 ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
 networks:
   - my_network
```

The NGINX config also needs to be modified to listen on 443 and configure SSL

```
listen              443 ssl http2;
server_name         myserver.com;
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
```

You can check From [NGINX to Traefik](https://medium.com/geekculture/from-nginx-to-traefik-with-docker-on-digitalocean-fcaeea3c6a4e) to see the details of NGINX configuration.